# asp form translating from another website

Tags: php, .net, forms, asp-classic, httprequest

first, I want to make a simple webpage that contains another website in it and replace text strings,

for example: when you open www.mywebsiteexample.com and find google.com (or any other website) with out redirecting, but instead of 'search' button you find some funny words,

the goal it to be able to translate some quizzes "with radio buttons and 'answer' button" from English into another language and translate the result by replacing strings of the questions with Indian or Chinese strings , and is it possible to change the CSS file of the page.

i was told that almost the only way is to use function called HttpRequest and catch the return and manipulate with it, but i don't know where to start.

how can i start, and is there any other way

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your trying to replace one string with another.  I believe this can be accomplished using innerHTML.  Here is a link http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php

Answer (score 0):

Hi there not sure what you exactly mean but you can get translation from here - http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html and if you need to execute some pages on your page then you can do like this - http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp

In the above page you execute another page in the background but you get result on your page by using ajax - this is a very good tutorial - if you need help understanding it - please let me know